# All of my /User/{username} files and folders are in my .git folder for some reason

Tags: git, macos, git-init

So currently I am trying to learn Git and am having a little trouble although many tutorials seem to be thorough and consistent.

When I type `git init` I get `/Users/{username}/.git/` which seems to be ok since the tutorials also return the same path.

But when I type `git status` I get every file and folder (both hidden and non hidden) that is in my `/Users/{username}/` directory for some reason, and it says all of those files/folders are untracked.

I don't want those files/folders in there as I only want my `.git` folder to contain my projects so I can proceed learning how to push projects into my remote repository (GitHub).

My system is Mac OSX, with OSX Sierra installed.

Comment: "When I type `git init` I get `/Users/username/.git/` which seems to be ok since the tutorials also return the same path." That's almost certainly not what you want. Running `git init` from your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) will make your entire home directory a Git repository. Git allows you to do that because it's a completely valid thing, but, again, not what you want. You will want to make a new directory for a particular project and run `git init` inside that directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior.  As you note:

> it says all of those files/folders are untracked.

This means those files are **not** in the Git repo, Git is only telling you that there are files that may be added.

While you can work from your `$HOME` directory if you want, I wouldn't advise it.  Instead, create a new folder just for your repo, and do your work there:

```
mkdir my-git-repo
cd my-git-repo
git init
```

To clean up the old Git repo, you can just delete it:

```
rm ~/.git
```